# Having difficulty in finding the existence of a location inside an area on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I have drawn a **polygon** on Google Maps. But I am unable to verify whether a point exists within that area. How can I achieve this? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Polygon</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_API_key&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
        var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(22.65, 88.45);
        var centerPoint2 = new google.maps.LatLng(28.3, 86.3167);
        var centerPoint3 = new google.maps.LatLng(22.65, 88.45);
        var centerPoint4 = new google.maps.LatLng(20.6333, 84.3167);
        var centerPoint5 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.6333, 85.3167);
        function Initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center: centerPoint,
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MyMap"), mapProp);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                  position: centerPoint,
                                                  animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                                               });
    var myTrip = [centerPoint2, centerPoint3, centerPoint4];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        path: myTrip,
                        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                        strokeOpacity: 0.2,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: "#B0F0FF",
                        fillOpacity: 0.4,
                        editable: true
                        });
            marker.setMap(map);
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    var locationExists = new  google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation({
                                    point: centerPoint5,
                                    polygon: flightPath
                                });
    document.getElementById("MyData").innerHTML = locationExists;
         }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MyMap" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="MyData" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Is the `containsLocation()` used properly? If not please suggest.

[image]

Comment: The image is not the same though..but the idea is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

**Note:** the geometry-library isn't loaded by default, you must load it by using the libraries-parameter of the maps-api

Comment: containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon) in this what should I provide in the polygon: ??? section?

Comment: the google.maps.Polygon-object where you want to detect if the point is within

Comment: please create a fiddle of your attempt, impossible to help without any code

Comment: oops! yeah, sorry. I'm...just wait a li'l.

Comment: Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'lng'

Comment: containsLocation expects 2 arguments, not both arguments wrapped into an object. also don't use it as a constructor. This should work: `var locationExists = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(centerPoint5,flightPath);` .But Note, this will return false for the example, because the point is not within, it's on the edge of the polygon. Use here `isLocationOnEdge` with a tolerance set to 1